# Can one extend one's French international driving permit in the United States?

Tags: usa, international-travel, paperwork, france, driving

A few years ago, I got an international driving permit while in France, issued by the [Paris Police Prefecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Police_Prefecture).

I read on the permit that it can be extended for 3 years:

[image]

Can I extend it while in the United States?

Comment: What is your place of residence? Form previous questions I believe you spend quite some time in the US, but I don’t know if you are a resident there. If you are, you are normally supposed to convert your French licence to a local one after some time (IIRC 6 months, though details may vary).

Comment: According to Wikipedia “_an international driving permit shall only be issued by the contracting party in whose territory the holder has their normal residence and that issued the domestic driving licence or that recognised the driving licence issued by another contracting party_”. So you need to be resident in the US for them (the AAA) to issue an IDP, and then the IDP is no longer valid there. Also note that many countries recognise the original licence directly, they don’t need an IDP.

Comment: If you are **not** a US resident then you can apparently apply for a renewal from the French authorities remotely. See https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F34812 for details depending on your specific case. Note that the IDP will be sent to your local embassy/consulate, apparently.

Comment: @jcaron thanks for the great information! You're welcome to post it as answer. I'm a US resident but I also know a French resident currently in the US for the winter vacation with the same question, so I'm interested in both cases.